# Vimscript to replace persian/arabic digits with english ones

Tags: replace, unicode, search-replace

I have a file that has so many persian/arabic digits in it. I would like to replace them with their English counterparts. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following `:s` command for Persian and Urdu digits:

```
:%s/\([۰-۹]\)/\=char2nr(submatch(1))-1776/g
```

And the following for Arabic digits:

```
:%s/\([۰-۹]\)/\=char2nr(submatch(1))-1536/g
```